# Treat only the n first item of a query

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a simple batch which export data from database to csv file.

The query pass in parameter is :

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
```

What I want is the step of my batch treat only the 10 first lines of the result query.
Equivalent to a query like this : `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 10`

Currently I do that in a specific RowMapper where I defined the methode `mapRow` like this :

```
public List<String> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    if ( rowNum <= 10) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        int nbColonnes = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i < nbColonnes+1; i++) {
            result.add(rs.getString(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But with this solution, if my query return 10 000 lines, the batch treat the 10 000 lines instead of just the 10 first.

What is the better way to do that in a step ?

Comment: why instead of `for (int i = 1; i < nbColonnes+1; i++) {` do not use `for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {` to get just the first 10?

Comment: @YCF_L, i think using that `for` loop they are trying to get columnar data into result.

Comment: @procrastinator Exactly ! The rowMapper is called for each line of the result, the for is here to return all the field of a line into in array.